# Deriving recurrence relations, very stuck!

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Going through past papers for my exams and cannot figure this one out, does anyone know how to do these?

The Bessel functions of integer order, Jn(x), are described by a generating function of the form:

[image]

Derive these recurrence relations:

[image]

[image]

The question advises that I do so by taking suitable derivatives, I'm trying this but not getting very far

Comment: Did you compute the derivative of G(x,h) with respect to h? What did you obtain?

Comment: Hint: $\color{red}{h\frac{\partial}{\partial h}} h^n = \color{red}{n}h^n$